instance scaling based on another curve
I have an instance on points based on spline A. How could I make the instances scale on the Z axis to curve B (each instance height reach B spline height) ?


Hope this helps:
ensure both curves have the same direction (reverse curve) and resample/subdivide them to the same amount of the points.



Thank you so much !
